# Need to include new module in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, morph-x

I am new in `Dynamics AX2012`. I need learn how can i create a new module. I want to know what are all the possible ways ?

Please guide me where I can get all the tutorial to tearn that

I just learn the `X++` language and I am ok to do with it

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules are called models in AX lingo.

Read all about [Models, Layers, and the Model Store](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh335184.aspx) and [Working with Models in AOT](http://dynamicspost.blogspot.dk/2012/03/model-management-in-ax-2012-differences.html).